How can i prevent some groups to do a drag in kanban columns?
I'm making a kanban view in Odoo 17 to display my model in columns based in a Many2one field.
And i want a some specific groups to not able to drag and sort in kanban columns.
I tried to add records_draggable="false" in
<kanban default_group_by="x_studio_stage_id" default_order="x_studio_priority desc, x_studio_sequence asc, id desc">

But even me, an administrator can't do the dragging. I want it only for some groups, not all the groups.

You can do it easily with Odoo's existing permissions without adding custom code and without breaking the existing columns permissions:
Solution using Server Actions
Without custom modules using Server Actions.
Something like this

In this example I used the CRM leads as an example, sensitive_field in the crm leads case would be stage_id.
To add server actions go to Settings / Technical / Actions / Server Actions
The group I'm using is "Sales / Administrator", but in the action code you need to use the external id, in this case sales_team.group_sale_manager.
You could easily modify the condition to allow multiple groups e.g: and user.has_group('sales_team.group_sale_manager') or user.has_group(sales_team.group_sale_salesman):
